# SQL Server 2005: I just executed [delete from allMyHardWorkTable] what are my options?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-restore

I just must have skipped a thought and executed that command. What is the easiest way that I can setup a "New Query" template which will prevent me from doing this again.

Is there a way to create a stored procedure to make myself an undo?

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Thank you everyone for all your help!

Comment: Not an answer ..But a 12 Pack of Bud is your friend for tonight :( .. unless ofcourse you have a backup of the DB

Comment: If your database recovery model was set to FULL, you could restore from transaction logs.  There's no much (if anything) we can do for you

Comment: What is a standard template I should have for a transaction to save my butt in the future? And it is set to FULL how do I recover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't execute the command within a transaction that you can rollback, you'll have to go to a backup my friend. If you don't have a backup of the DB data, you are unfortunately FUBAR'd :(

Comment: Thank you! What is the standard code template I should wrap all my statements in?

Comment: `BEGIN TRANSACTION
... SQL STATEMENTS ...`
Then `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` will restore the DB to the state it was prior to the start of the Transaction. `COMMIT TRANSACTION` will make the results of the statements persistent. Here's more info about [Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to get your data back is by restoring your most recent backup.

Comment: lol, great that one is last sunday, thanks!